# Failed to resolve component: VuePhoneNumberInput in @ionic-vue

Tags: vue.js, ionic-vue

I installed a global component in @ionic-vue, but when using it in another component I get the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: VuePhoneNumberInput    at
> <Registro ref=Ref< undefined > key="/registro" isInOutlet=true  ... >
> at     at     at 
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38

[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve

> component: VuePhoneNumberInput    at <Registro ref=Ref<  Proxy {
> : {…}, : {…} }
>
> > key="/registro" isInOutlet=true  ... >    at     at     at

My global register:

```
import VuePhoneNumberInput from 'vue-phone-number-input';
import 'vue-phone-number-input/dist/vue-phone-number-input.css';

import './theme/variables.css';

const app = createApp(App)
  .use(IonicVue)
  .use(router);
  
app.component('vue-phone-number-input', VuePhoneNumberInput);
```

Other component:

```
<template>
<ion-page>
    <Navigacion :titulo="titulo">
    <template v-slot:default>
       <div class="titulo-login">Ingresa a Jamuy con tu número de celular</div>
     <VuePhoneNumberInput v-model="numero" @update="resultados = $event"></VuePhoneNumberInput>
     </template>
    </Navigacion>
</ion-page>
</template>
```